# Block visits that uses a strange parameter (?mdrv=)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have received (one time per month, not something to be worried but just strange) scraping visits that use a determined parameter: `?mdrv=`. The problem is that these visits are from different IPs so blocking the IP is not a solution.

For example: `example.com/?mdrv=`, `/category/the_category?mdrv=` or `/year/month/article.html?mdrv=` (home page, category pages, post pages from home page or megamenu or simple pages in menu like `/contact`).

I´m trying to block this one but I cant get the correct code to block them (I get the one for home page but not for the others). How can I block them all?

Comment: Why worry about it? It sounds like it isn't causing any problems.

Comment: "I get the one for home page but not for the others" - Please edit your question to show the rule you are using. It should be the same rule to block all such requests.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller it causes the server to fall during a couple of minutes each time this strange visits asked for url with this strange parameter. Not so important but I was interesnting on knowing how to block them if happens more than one time each 15-30 days.

Comment: "Why worry about it? It sounds like it isn't causing any problems." <- In my case, the bot isn't respecting my `robots.txt` and it's hitting the site many times within the same second. It's an IP in Germany, FWIW which isn't honest about its user agent.

Comment: Did you figure out what `mdrv` is? Our server is called with `GET /some-file-on-site?mdrv=www.our-domain-name.com` now and then, came to attention today when MariaDB connections failed with 'too many connections', seemed like a flood of requests at the same time.  Searching Google, I only found HP Loadrunner and "Virtual User Generator" has an mdrv.exe program, I wonder if it's that? Origin IP 165.22.159.123 is Digital Ocean cloud hosting in California.  I will probably block all `?mdrv` requests with an Apache Rewrite rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```
# revised answer

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mdrv=
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

# original answer

# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^?]*\?mdrv=
# RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Why check THE_REQUEST rather than QUERY_STRING?  I'd think your regex could be simpler in the latter case.

Comment: True. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mdrv=` might be best